# Opening JAR with building-tools?

Tags: java, jar, console, minecraft, build-tools

I am trying to run the JAR "buildtools.jar" but a message keeps popping up:

> The Java JAR file "BuildTools.jar" could not be launched.

in smaller writing underneath:

> Check the Console for possible error messages.

The console says

```
12/31/14 10:19:44.021 AM WindowServer[113]: _CGXGetWindowMovementGroup: Operation on a window 0x14 requiring rights 0x5 by caller Dashboard or 12/31/14 10:19:44.021 AM DashboardClient[2747]: _NXMoveWindow: error moving window (1000)
```

every time I try to open the jar thing up. I know that my Java is updated because I updated before trying anything with this.
I am trying to create a minecraft server with spigot and if you have a step by step process or any hinters about please tell me but my main focus is opening up the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't the very right place to ask this question. You can ask this question at the [Spigot Forums](http://www.spigotmc.org/forums/).

Are you using the very latest version of BuildTools? You seem like running on MacOS. You may need to run it with this flag, `-Dmac.supported=true`(refer to [this](http://www.spigotmc.org/threads/spigot-buildtools-for-mac-osx.40646) post). Also, `The Java JAR file "BuildTools.jar" could not be launched.` most likely, you have a broken Jar file. Try to re-download it from {1}(I need 10 population to post more than 2 links). You will also need JDK(Java Development Kits) but I think it is came by default in MacOS and Git {2}.
After you've installed all required things, you can run the BuildTools from Terminal by `java -Dmac.supported=true -jar BuildTools.jar` You need to wait few minutes for it to be finished.

Comment: {1}: https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/BuildTools.jar

Comment: {2}: git-scm.com/download/mac